# Excel / LibreOffice Calc Partial Match in Reverse

Tags: excel, excel-formula, libreoffice, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

I would like to use a lookup table to choose a tag for each row according to its description column. Descriptions contain keywords that map to tags. Therefore, I need to partially match against the keyword list as below:

```
  A                     B          C        D        E
1 Description           Tag                 Keyword  Tag
2 lorem KEYA ipsum                          KEYA     Tag A
3 dolor sit KEYC amet                       KEYB     Tag B
4 KEYB consectetur                          KEYC     Tag C
5 adipiscing elit KEYA                      KEYD     Tag D
6 sed do KEYB eiusmod
```

I would like to fill cells in column B with values from the lookup table in D2:E5. I could use something like

> =VLOOKUP(".*"&$A2&".*", $D$3:$E$6, 2, 0)

but it won't work because I try to match full text against partial texts.

> =VLOOKUP($A2, ".*"&$D$3:$E$6&".*", 2, 0)

does not work either. Apparently regular expressions are only supported in the search criterion. And I don't like to write something like

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("KEYA",$A2)), "Tag A", 
 IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("KEYB",$A2)), "Tag B", 
 IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("KEYC",$A2)), "Tag C", 
 IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("KEYD",$A2)), "Tag D", 
 ""))))
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Parse the KEY*x* text from column A to use as the *lookup_value* in your `VLOOKUP`.

[image: Tag wildcard lookup]

The formula in B2 is `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(MID(A2,FIND("KEY",A2),4),$C$2:$D$5,2,FALSE),"")`.

*Addendum:* For OpenOffice/LibreOffice:

[image]

The formula for B2 would be `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(MID(A2;FIND("KEY";A2);4);$C$2:$D$5;2;0));"";VLOOKUP(MID(A2;FIND("KEY";A2);4);$C$2:$D$5;2;0))`. Fill down as necessary.

Comment: Thanks, but not all my keywords contain "KEY" init. They are arbitrary keywords. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this array formula in B2 using Ctrl-Shift-Enter and copying it down:-

```
=INDEX(E$2:E$5,MAX((NOT(ISERROR(FIND(D$2:D$5,A2)))*ROW(D$2:$D$5))-1))
```

It uses FIND to try and match each of the keys in turn anywhere in A2. If one matches, it works out the corresponding row number in D$2:D$5. It takes the maximum matching row, and uses INDEX to find the corresponding element in E$2:E$5. If there is no matching key, it gives a #VALUE! error.

The matching with FIND is case-sensitive: if you didn't want it to be case-sensitive, you would need to use SEARCH instead of FIND.

If you could ever have a case with two or more matching keys, e.g.

```
lorem KEYA KEYB ipsum
```

you would get the last matching one in the list i.e. TAG B.

[image]

Comment: `FIND(D$2:D$5,A2)` part does not seem to work in LibreOffice. I always get "#VALUE!" I will try with Excel.

Comment: I haven't tried it in LibreOffice but it works OK in Excel and OpenOffice. The only difference using OpenOffice (apart from the semicolons) was that I had to copy and paste the array formula down instead of pulling it down. If you put the FIND part in on its own, you should get the value 7 followed by three #VALUE! cells - these are removed in the formula that I gave in my answer by the ISERROR function.