# Lookup in LibreOffice Calc to match partial string of the search criterion

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I'm putting my banking information in a LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet.

I have columns as follows, that I imported from my bank account:

```
Date      | USD   | Description                                 | Category
----------+-------+---------------------------------------------+----------
2/28/2019 | 44.00 | POS 0123 2345 123456 FRED-MEYER #02         | groceries
2/27/2019 |  2.50 | PANDA EXPRESS #123 TIGARD OR - 123546789012 | lunch
```

These descriptions are very unpredictable, they're whatever merchants want them to be, but they can tell me useful information about what I spent my money on. I've used this information to manually enter the categories. But I'm looking to automate this for common things.

So, I created a separate sheet with lookup values, like so:

```
Expression | Category
-----------+----------
FRED-MEYER | groceries
PANDA      | lunch
```

I am looking for a formula in the "Category" column of the first sheet to automatically determine categories, based on the lookup table in the second sheet. (Obviously I don't plan for the lookup table to be exhaustive, but whatever I don't put in there, I can enter in the first sheet manually, thus overwriting the formulas.)

I had this working fine in Excel using a nifty construct of `SEARCH` and `MATCH`. (I don't even understand it anymore and I don't have Excel to check.) But since I'm now a Linux user, I'm trying to use LibreOffice, and I've not been able to make this work with formulas. I tried `SEARCH`, `MATCH`, `LOOKUP`, `VLOOKUP`, `FIND`, with and without regexes and with different options on/off. But no success so far.

I think this is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26340878/excel-libreoffice-calc-partial-match-in-reverse), though it was only answered for Excel (I'm using Calc).

Comment: The `VLOOKUP()` function would be a good place to start

Comment: Thank you, but as I said, I tried using it, and I'm not seeing how it would satisfy the requirement.